# Nested models in Play Framework 1.2.7 templates

Tags: java, playframework

I have models:

Switch:

```
@Entity
public class Switch extends Model {

/** Management IP */
public String managementIP;

/** Hostname description, e.g. lan-bc-sw2 */
public String hostname;

/** Switch state, e.g. active */
public String status;

/** Swith model, e.g. C2960-48TS-L */
public String model;

/** IOS version */
public String osVersion;

/** Switch ports */
@OneToMany
public List<Port> ports;

...
```

Port:

```
@Entity
public class Port extends Model {

/** Switch port id, e.g. Gi0/1 */
public String portID;

/** Switch port description */
public String description;

/** Switch port type, e.g. 10/100BaseTX */
public String type;

/** Switch port VLAN */
@ManyToOne
public VLAN vlan;

/** Is switch port int trunk mode? */
public boolean isTrunk = false;

/** Switch port speed */
public String speed;

/** Switch port duplex mode */
public String duplex;

/** Port state */
public String state;

/** Port security*/
@OneToOne
public PortSecurity portSecurity;
...
```

VLAN:

```
@Entity
public class VLAN extends Model {

/** VLAN id, e.g. 5 */
public int vlanID;

/** VLAN description */
public String description;

/** VLAN status, e.g. active */
public String state;`
....
```

Pass to template:

```
public static void index(long switch_id) {
    Switch sw = Switch.findById(switch_id);
    render(sw);
}
```

Then, when i try to get VLAN from port:

```
#{list items:sw.getPorts(), as:'port'}

    <tr>
      <td>${port.portID}</td>
      <td>${port.description}</td>
      <td class="center">
      <td>${port.vlan.state}</td>

      ....
```

Im getting: Execution error occured in template /app/views/Switches/index.html. Exception raised was NullPointerException : Cannot get property 'state' on null object.

But, if i do `port.vlan.toString()`, im getting all VLAN fields with correct data!

Help, please...

Comment: Nobody know, how to solve this problem?

Comment: There is one thing seems to be weird to me. Why do you use `sw.getPorts()` when you can reach ports of switch simply through `sw.ports` ? What is your implementation of getPorts()?

Comment: There is simple getter (return ports field). I try getPorts() with same issue...